# Uncaught TypeError in D3 Sankey Drag Function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, typeerror

I have created a d3 Sankey graph. The issue that I'm facing is that I am unable to drag the nodes.
This is how the node is created:

```
 var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click",highlight_node_links)
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("dragstart", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
      .on("drag", dragmove));
```

And the dragmove function is as follows:

```
 function dragmove(d) {

    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + (
               d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - d.dx, d3.event.x))
            ) + "," + (
                   d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
            ) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);
  }
```

But everytime I run my code, it throws this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null**

What am I doing wrong?

[image: If I click on the error, it takes me to a blank line on the index page]

Comment: I don't see any property "target" being read. Do you know which line the error is from? If so, can you please indicate it?

Comment: None of these lines.. And I am not able to figure out which line throws an error. I tried adding debugger to the dragmove function, but it seems the loop is not being entered @JonathanLam

Comment: Do you see this error when you drag or when the code inits?  It looks like you are following d3noobs code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c9b90689c1438f57d649), right?  In order to troubleshoot further, you'll need to create a jsfiddle or plunker that reproduces the error.  My guess would that there are links referring to non-existent nodes....

Comment: @Mark Error occurs when I try to drag the nodes and not on initialization. Yes, the d3noob's one of my references. I will try and create a jsfiddle though. That will be more clear. :)

Comment: I've made the example with your functions here: https://plnkr.co/edit/mhwhWYDPdUr1t0R2H3fG?p=preview and it woks fine. Could you fork this to reproduce your code.

Comment: There's another issue which I'm facing. When I define d3 using <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script> the graph is fine (with the drag functionality working). But if I create a local copy of d3.v3.js and link it as <script src="d3.v3.js"></script> throws an error saying d3 not defined!

Comment: Thanks @Klaujesi though

Comment: Use this CDN version: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js it's a minified. Copy to your local folder and call it: <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was being thrown because of the placement of the script in the program. While integrating the graph into a page with a lot of other content, I placed the script in the head section which seemed to cause the issue. Now that, I placed it near the end, everything works fine. I'm sorry to have posted this, I was being silly.

```
  <html>
   <style><!-- Style for the Sankey graph -->
   </style>
   <body>
      <div id="sankey-graph">
      </div>
      <script><!-- Script for the Sankey graph -->
      </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

This is the correct way I guess. I had initially put my script before the div that contained sankey graph.